# Is it good to use margin or padding in bootstrap class?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I could not understand about that, I need your help to understand this point.

**Is it good to use margin or padding with bootstrap class by using another class (which will call margin or padding in css)?**

Please check an example below for better understanding:

```html
<div class="row margin-bottom-30">
  <div class="col-xs-10 padding-30">
    <p>text here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already know col-xs-10 and all the col-xx-xx classes have a default left and right padding of 15px. If you want to increase that, it's ok, it's nothing wrong with that, depends of what your design should look like.

Regarding the row class, to use a margin-bottom it is actually fine, it's quite recommanded for spaces between blocks. What i think it's not recomanded is to use margin left and right inside col-xs-10 because it could crash the layout. The rest of the things are permited.

Comment: Well, I will not use padding in bootstrap class. But can i use margin class and bootstrap class together?

Comment: Depends on what bootstrap class you mean, and what margin type you mean, if you want to use a margin-bottom class along with bootstrap row class, it's no problem.. you can do that. It's the only way you can design a custom layout.

Answer (score 0):

It's fine to use use..
But it is not according to our standards.
SO, do not change the padding of existing bootstrap class..
it's better to add a parent  with a class and give padding in it.

This will be in case of Media Queries

Comment: Well, I will not use padding in bootstrap class. But can i use margin class and bootstrap class together?

Comment: well you can add margin but it might break the alignment in some cases and to fix that you have to add other stuffs...     And all these are unnecessary css lines